# Hero defeats the demon lord and is then reincarnated into the future as a loser noble

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

The story itself is just your average "hero defeats the demon lord" who is reincarnated by said demon lord into the future.

He ends up reincarnated as a loser noble, but the specifics are things like that this new body of his wasn't fully aware of himself and just bided his days, while his "genius" brother, who for some reason hates the main character (MC), is going around trying to degrade him at every moment, like making the MC's fiancée date him just to spite the MC.

And of course, after he gains awareness, he ends up being the strongest dude at school, while not caring about what his new brother is doing, which only makes him angrier.

Thanks to anyone who actually answers this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also what colour hair did the MC and his brother have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is *[Ochikobore Datta Ani ga Jitsu wa Saikyou: Shijou Saikyou no Yuusha wa Tenseishi, Gakuen de Mujikaku ni Musou suru](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/ochikobore-datta-ani-ga-jitsu-wa-saikyou-shijou-saikyou-no-yuusha-wa-tenseishi-gakuen-de-mujikaku-ni-musou-suru)*.

> Eugene, a hero, is **forcibly reincarnated by the demon king Venomzard**. In a world far in the future, **he becomes a noble boy named Julius**. Freed from his "hero" mission, Julius decides to enjoy his second life and his school life. However, **his brother, Gaias, mocks him, and his parents and teachers consider him a failure**. Having been reincarnated with the immense power of his previous life, Julius unknowingly becomes a warrior ...!

The synopsis covers most of the details of the question. He wakes up after reincarnation as a teenager, with his body having been on "autopilot" for his younger years. His family hates him, especially his younger brother, and everyone thinks he's incompetent.

After reincarnation, he keeps his original power from his past life, and this far into the future, everyone else has become incompetent, with the most basic magic of his past being treated as extremely advanced.

The fiance scene happens in chapter 2. Despite being incompetent and despised, he is apparently engaged to a beautiful princess, except she and his younger brother are more interested in each other and openly flirt.

[image: Fiance] [image: Fiance 2]

Comment: Thank you, I've been racking my brain for the past week trying to remember this manga